# css put and arrow pointing to IMAGE?

Tags: css

I have no idea how can I put an arrow in the same color of my div pointing to the IMAGE text.
Some ideas? how can I do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/fvvrLqLp/

```
#arrow{
 background-color:#FFD600;
 color:#fff;
 border-radius:15px;
 padding:5px;
 z-index:999;
 max-width:150px;
}
```

html:

```
 image<br><br>
    <div id="arrow">
    text
    </div>
```

thank you friends!

Comment: use an SVG either inline or base64

Comment: I want the arrow in the ballow, with css! @MatthewRath /\

Comment: an arrow in the top left pointing to the image text

Comment: Do you mean the mouse pointer as an arrow? Or an arrow as a kind of overlay image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for something like that:

```
#arrow {
  background-color: #FFD600;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 999;
  max-width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

#arrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 20px;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ffd600;
}
```

An example: https://jsfiddle.net/fvvrLqLp/1/

You need to create the triangle with css into a pseudo element and position it accordingly to the needed position.

Comment: @some-non-descript-user I updated the answer, if you want more information about css shapes check this out: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: @Vangel Tzo: Thank you very much for the link.